# I've received single item from api

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit

I trying to display temperature values that came from the API response in RecyclerView. The thing is my program constantly display just one, first item. I'm not sure where can be the issue, and I feel a bit lost in it.

**Part of the api response that I want to display**

```
"hourly": [
{
  "dt": 1607184000,
  "temp": x,
  "feels_like": x,
  "pressure": x,
  "humidity": x,
  "dew_point": x,
  "uvi": x,
  "clouds": x,
  "visibility": x,
  "wind_speed": x,
  "wind_deg": x,
  "pop": x
},
and so on...
```

**Model class**

```
public class ForecastModel {
@SerializedName("hourly")
private List<HourlyForecast> hourlyForecast = null;

public List<HourlyForecast> getHourlyForecast() {
    return hourlyForecast;
}
public class HourlyForecast{
    @SerializedName("dt")
    private int dt;

    public int getDt() {
        return dt;
    }
}
```

}

**Activity class**

```
    public class HourlyForecastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "HourlyForecastActivity";
    private List<ForecastModel> mData = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    HourlyForecastAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hourly_forecast);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.hourly_recycler_view);
        adapter = new HourlyForecastAdapter();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        prepareConnection();
    }
   private void prepareConnection(){
        ForecastViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ForecastViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getData().observe(this, new Observer<ForecastModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ForecastModel forecast) {
                if (mData.size() > 0){
                    mData.clear();
                }
                if (forecast != null){
                    mData.addAll(Collections.singleton(forecast));
                    adapter.setData(mData);
                }
            }
        });
   }
}
```

**Adapter class**

```
    public class HourlyForecastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HourlyForecastAdapter.HourlyViewHolder> {
    private List<ForecastModel> mHourlyData = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setData(List<ForecastModel> mHourlyData){
        this.mHourlyData = mHourlyData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HourlyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hourly_items, parent, false);
        return new HourlyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HourlyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ForecastModel model = mHourlyData.get(position);
        holder.mTemperature.setText(String.valueOf(model.getHourlyForecast().get(position).getDt()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mHourlyData.size();
    }

    public class HourlyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTemperature, mPressure, mHumidity, mWindSpeed, mDescription;
        private ImageView mIcon;

        public HourlyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTemperature = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hourly_temperature);
            mPressure = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hourly_pressure);
            mHumidity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hourly_humidity);
            mWindSpeed = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hourly_wind_speed);
            mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hourly_description);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok  to me. Make sure your `R.layout.hourly_items` has `android:layout_height="wrap_content`.

Comment: It is set to wrap content. I even tried to log the data, but same story - just the very first data. I find that out whenever I use the for loop for log the "dt", it is printing it as far as I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setData` method in your adapter is a bit misleading (naming and variable wise). Looking at your `onChanged` method in the `Activity`: a single `ForecastModel` object is what you are working with. Passing that object to the adapter in `setData` as a `List` named `mHourlyData` is what's causing the initial confusion. That `List` will alway be of size 1, causing the problem you are facing.

I recommend changing the `onChanged` method call to simply do this:

```java
adapter.setData(forecast)
```

And rename the adapter variable in `setData` to reflect what your actually are receiving (want to receive):

```java
private List<HourlyForecast> mHourlyForecast = new ArrayList<>();

public void setData(ForecastModel forecast){
    this.mHourlyForecast = forecast.hourlyForecast;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

After that, the only thing left to do is update your `getItemCount` and `onBindViewHolder` methods accordingly.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!